# ES6 Generator Function vs Promises

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

Please let me know if this is too vague of a question, but what are the advantages of using an ES6 generator function as opposed to promises? I don't see the advantage at the moment and was hoping someone could shed some light on it.

For example, when retrieving data in an asynchronous manner:

```
/* Using promises */
fetch('api-endpoint')
   .then( resp => response.json() )
   .then( name => obj.name)
   .then( x => console.log('Name: ', name) )

//VS

/* As a generator function and assuming we have required node-fetch */
run(function *() {
   const url = 'api-endpoint';
   const resp = yield fetch(url);
   const obj = yield response.json();
   const name = yield obj.name;
   console.log("Name available here: ", name); 
}

function run(genFunc) {
   const iterator = genFunc();
   const iteration = iterator.next();
   const promise = iteration.value();
   promise.then( x => {
      const additionalIterator = iterator.next(x);
      const additionalPromise = iterator.value;
      additionalPromise.then( y => iterator.next(y));
   });
}
```

Comment: It is pretty vague. Can you show how you would use them to do similar things?

Comment: No problem, will add an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Promises deal with asynchronous events, while generators provide a powerful tool for writing loops and algorithms that maintain their own state.

From [MDN Iterator and generators page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators)

> Processing each of the items in a collection is a very common
>   operation. JavaScript provides a number of ways of iterating over a
>   collection, from simple for loops to map() and filter(). Iterators and
>   Generators bring the concept of iteration directly into the core
>   language and provide a mechanism for customizing the behavior of
>   for...of loops.

So I think they are intended to solve two very different issues.

Having said that, [you *could* use generators instead of promises](http://www.2ality.com/2015/03/no-promises.html), like in your example, but I don't think that's what they were intended for.

Comment: No problem, it is a useful comment so I upvoted it. I was only looking at them in terms of dealing with async events, but they certainly seem to be more practical when dealing with blocking of loops, etc. Just trying to wrap my head around them.

Comment: Sure I'm far from an expert on the matter myself. You could go ahead and accept it, if it helped you ;) @DanWeber